# What is the library and functions to get the name of Microphone device for audio recording in MFC program?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mfc

I'm trying to capture screen and audio coincidance in MFC.

So, I choose the FFmpeg library and I called command line for capturing in MFC.
Video capture is so so, but in Audio capture, there is a problem:
My MFC program doesn't know about name of the microphone.
So, I can't capture audio side.

If you have experience with FFmpeg, please help me.

Comment: Which language are you programming in, C **or** C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ allows operator and function overloading.  Some compilers use a scheme called name mangling to differentiate the overloaded functions.  Some libraries may not be compatible with this scheme.  Please update your language tags, unless you are mixing the languages; I don't recommend mixing the languages since it makes the program more complex.

Comment: See also [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Show us some code you are trying.

Comment: What about this? windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream)

Comment: If you can require users of your application to use Windows 10, [Windows.Media.Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices) is probably the easiest way to enumerate devices, and record video and audio. That allows you to drop FFmpeg entirely.